# I am getting a thread error when attempting to open a form based on a timer tick event

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, timer, invoke

I have a program that runs a scoretable front screen. I want to have a running ad loop of videos that pop up based on a timer. I created a separate form to play the video and am using a timer to open the form and play one video, then I am incrementing a global variable, closing the form, then waiting for the timer to reopen the form. When the timer tries to reopen the form, it is giving me a thread error. I am somewhat new to this level of coding and am confused about why this error is occuring and how to fix it. I read up on the topic and think I generally understand the problem, but can't seem to find the proper code to get it to work. Here is the code (global variable of VAds) I have used the invoke procedure to fix this problem with a picture box, but cant figure out the same thing for the video. Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub PlayAdVideos(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles VideoAds.Click
        On Error Resume Next
        If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of frmAds).Any Then
            frmVideoAds.Close()
            Play_Ads.Text = "Start Video Advertisement Loop"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Play_Ads.Text = "Close Video Advertisement Loop"
            Dim Sz As Integer
            If ScreenNo.Text = "" Then
                Sz = 1
            Else
                Sz = ScreenNo.Text
            End If

            Dim screen As Screen
            screen = Screen.AllScreens(Sz)
            frmVideoAds.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
            frmVideoAds.Location = screen.Bounds.Location + New Point(0, 0)
            frmVideoAds.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
            frmVideoAds.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
            frmVideoAds.TopMost = True
            frmVideoAds.BackColor = Color.Black
            frmVideoAds.Show()
        End If

        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\CCHS\VideoAds\")
            VideoAdList.Items.Add(foundFile)
        Next

        If VideoAdList.Items.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim TMR2 As New System.Timers.Timer()

        VideoAdNum = VideoAdList.Items.Count - 1

        TMR2.Interval = 10000 'miliseconds
        TMR2.Enabled = True
        TMR2.Start()
        AddHandler TMR2.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent

    End Sub

    Public Sub OnTimedEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)

        If frmVideoAds.InvokeRequired Then
            If VAds = VideoAdNum Then
                VAds = 0
            Else
                VAds = VAds + 1
            End If
            frmVideoAds.Invoke(Sub() frmVideoAds.Show())
        Else
            If VAds = VideoAdNum Then
                VAds = 0
            Else
                VAds = VAds + 1
            End If
            frmVideoAds.Show()

        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: What programming language is that? Please add a tag in order to make this more useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Timers.Timer elapsed events will generally always be fired on a thread other than the UI thread.

Which means you'll have to call the frmVideoAds.Invoke every time you call frmVideoAds.Show() in that method.

Your else statement should just need to have the invoke added, which would make both execution paths the same so you could update the whole thing.

```
 Public Sub OnTimedEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
            If VAds = VideoAdNum Then
                VAds = 0
            Else
                VAds = VAds + 1
            End If
            frmVideoAds.Invoke(Sub() frmVideoAds.Show())
    End Sub
```

This will generally work, but in some cases , ActiveX in particular, the System.Timers is required to be in a Single Threaded Apartment (STA). It defaults to a Multi threaded apartment (MTA). To force it into a STA mode simply add

```
TMR2.SynchronizingObject = Me
```

just before your TM2.Start().

Comment: Thanks James. I tried that, but I am still getting an error on the "frmVideoAds.InvokeRequired" line                System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: ActiveX control '6bf52a52-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.

Comment: given that you need the Invoke every time, you could get rid of the If statement altogether. After adding it to the Else, both execution paths would be the same. i.e. no reason to check if it needs an invoke, it needs one regardless.

Comment: still throwing an error.  Is this the right syntax? I was just making an educated guess. 'code' frmVideoAds.Invoke(Sub() frmVideoAds.Show())

Comment: Ah, that inner exception changes it. ActiveX needs single threaded apartment thread. Your System.Timers defaults to MTA, but you may be able to force it to STA by adding 

TMR2.SynchronizingObject = Me just before your TMR2.Start() call

Comment: You sir, are brilliant.  That fixed the issue. Thanks for the help